# Flutter How can I expand a widget into a bigger widget with more content?

Tags: flutter, animation, widget, expand

I have a rectangle with some text inside a list and I want to expand this rectangle when the user taps on in into a bigger rectangle with more content in it

**For example this is my initial widget:**

[image]

**And when the user taps on "Rect 1" I want it to expand into:**

[image]

Comment: You're looking for an expansion tile.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new animations package from flutter. It allows you to add animations to expand the container into a larger container and that will able to show larger content.

Here you can find the link for the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/animations

Here you can find how to implement it if you'd like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHzAJdlEj1c

Hope this answers your question and helps you out. This isn't very complicated to implement such as put a gesture detector etc.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to wrap the widget in a Gesture detector and set the onTap method to alternate a boolean variable and then according to the value of that variable you decide whether to show the additional stuff or not.

Here is an example :

```
class Test extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  TestState createState() => TestState() ;

}

class TestState extends State<Test> {

bool showPlus = false ; 

  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
     body : GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
        setState (() {
          (showPlus) ? showPlus = false :showPlus = true ;
        });
  }, 
  child: Column(
   children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20 , vertical: 20),
              child: Text(
                  'Rect 1',
              ),
            ),
            (showPlus) ? Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.white,),
                Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.white,),
                Container(width: 100 , height: 100, color: Colors.white,),
              ],
            ) : SizedBox.shrink()
          ],
       )
      )
    );
   }
 }
```